# Which strategy to choose when doing long running tasks on Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am creating an application that will download around 30 images. Let's say it takes more than 10 seconds. I have been reading about `AsyncTask` and I guess that it shouldn't be used since the task will take more than a couple of seconds.

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds
>   at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of
>   time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by
>   the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor
>   and FutureTask.

When looking at the API for `ASyncTask` I see there are methods that can publish to the UI thread. If I have understood it right a more proper way to do long running task is to use a `FutureTask`? That means that I have to post updates to the UI thread myself. Is it correct that you use the [`post(Runnable)` method of View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29)?

I could need some guidance whether or not I am on the right track.

Comment: Use IntentService or Background service to execute long task...

Answer (score 4):

You can understand short operations as operations that are related to the lifecycle of your Activity.

You can update the UI using the `onProgressUpdate()` callback which is executed on the UI thread.

However if your Activity goes on pause during the process, this is likely to crash so you should cancel your task in onPause() using `task.cancel(true)`;

If you need your task to survive your activity, then you should use either a Service or a ServiceIntent. The former is a bit more complex as you have to manage its lifecycle but offers  more flexibility. The second is damn straightforward so I can give you an example here:

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService{

public MyIntentService() {
    super("MyIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Background work in a worker thread (async)

    // You could also send a broadcast if you need to get notified
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("whatever");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
}
```

The you can start if from your activity with

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
context.startService(i);
```

Comment: So when do you use the things that the documentation mentions as alternatives to AsyncTask such as FutureTask, Executors etc? Nothing is mentioned about this.

Comment: I've never used a FutureTask in my android projects. It's a generic java AsyncTask (it's not Android specific) offering a more flexible interface than a Thread. I can't see any use case where a FutureTask should be preferred to an AsyncTask (Android specific) as the latter offers a very convenient way to interact with the UI thread before, during and after the background job.

Comment: I have to run multiple operations together which might get executed while the user is interacting with different activities. I cannot user Intent Service as running multiple Intent Service will execute them one by one and not parallelly. Using service is also a problem as the Android OS will kill it if it is running for more than 1 minute while the user is not using the app or has minimized the app thinking to return back to the app in a few minutes. Which method would you recommend? A Thread? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

AsyncTasks don't follow Activity instances' life cycle. If you start an AsyncTask inside an Activity and you rotate the device, the Activity will be destroyed and a new instance will be created. But the AsyncTask will not die. It's one of the reasons that it is advised to avoid AsyncTask for long running tasks.

I believe in your case Simple `threading` will be sufficient because you are only downloading data. If you need to update UI elements, you can use Handlers as well.

**Edit:**

You can't update the UI during the FutureTask is performing its job. UI can only be updated once the it's finished its job.

```
A FutureTask can be used to wrap a Callable or Runnable object. Because FutureTask 
implements Runnable, a FutureTask can be submitted to an Executor for execution.
```

Comment: You can wrap Handlers with FutureTask, so you can update the UI with it.

Comment: But what about the post method that I linked to that is available from the View class then?

Comment: As I said you can update the UI but after futureTask has retrieved all the data. Unlike AsyncTask where you can post the progress/ update UI while the data is being retrieved.

Comment: I have to run multiple operations together which might get executed while the user is interacting with different activities. I cannot user Intent Service as running multiple Intent Service will execute them one by one and not parallelly. Using service is also a problem as the Android OS will kill it if it is running for more than 1 minute while the user is not using the app or has minimized the app thinking to return back to the app in a few minutes. Which method would you recommend? A Thread? Or something else?